# Передать значение из фрагмента в активность

Tags: java, android

В чем проблемам? ругается на `final String get_image = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE);`

Получатель(активность)

```
       public static final String EXTRA_TITLE = "get_title";
    public static final String EXTRA_ID = "get_id";
    public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "get_image";
   final String get_image = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE);
    final String get_title = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
    final String get_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_ID);
```

отправитель (фрагмент)

```
  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailInform.class);
            intent.putExtra(DetailInform.EXTRA_TITLE, ho.mBoundTitle);
            intent.putExtra(DetailInform.EXTRA_ID, ho.mBoundID);
            intent.putExtra(DetailInform.EXTRA_IMAGE, ho.mBoundImage);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Если в onCreate получать значения то все нормально (они приходят) но тогда я не могу их вытащить из onCreate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получатель должен быть в on create, потому что именно этот метод вызывается, когда вы запускаете активность с помощью Intent. Чтобы сохранить значение, добавьте поля в класс активности.

Comment: Можете написать как мне это сделать или с помощью чего(Метод)

Comment: через  private void setupIntent(){} и добавить в create setupIntent()?

Comment: @joni просто поместите ваш код 'пооучатель' в конец onCreate. Затем создайте в классе активности поля и присвойте там же в onCreate им значения из Intent